# mongoose check if getById has a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wish to search a document by Id and check if that document has a certain field. If user has the field, the image with that filename will be deleted. But there is a problem with my query

```
exports.updateImage = function(userId, image, cb){
    console.log(image);
    userSchema.findById(userId, { image : {$exists : true}}, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        console.log(err);
        if(user){
            fs.unlick('./public/' + user.image);
        }
    });
    userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
        "image" : image
    }, cb);
};
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing, and please show your `userSchema`.

Comment: /Users/thomasengels/Documents/yathzee-backend/model-controllers/users.js:90
  {safe: true, upsert: true}
                           ^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
 ..... `var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar : {
    type: Buffer
  },
  image : {
    type: String
  }
});`

Comment: Hi user1008531 - when you have more information about your problem, it's best to edit your question to include the new information. That way, it is more easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I lost an ')' in the end, I read the error, but after looking and looking, I couldn't find the typo, but now I see it. My mistake

```
userSchema.findById(userId, { image : {$exists : true}}, function(err, user){       if(user){
        fs.unlick('./public/' + user.image);
    }
});
userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
    "image" : image
}, cb);
```

Comment: Hi user1008531. If you have solved your problem yourself, the best thing to do is to write up how you solved it in an answer here, and then Accept your answer so the question doesn't show up on the unanswered list any more.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot [you have to wait 48 hours](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).